# Programmatically selecting imageViews from ArrayList or HashMap

Tags: android, arraylist, imageview

I have a Farkle game that I am trying to create a "Computer" player for and I am having a tough time trying to get this to work.

Game Play: 1's & 5's are always scorable, Straight 1-6, 3-of-a-kind, 4-of-a-kind, 5-of-a-kind & 6-of-a-kind are scorable.  Pairs are only scorable if using all 6 dice. example: 2,2,5,5,4,4.

So here is my issue.  I have it selecting all dice just to make it work, but I want to find the Value of the dice that are showing on the board and these scorable combinations and select them programmatically 1-by-1. The screen shot shows the human player has selected the 5.  I  know the code is a mess (I have been told several times). FYI, I had to remove a lot of code to stay in the 30000 limit. Complete Code is [here](https://github.com/soboapps/AI_OhFark)

[image: Farkle Screen Shot]

Here are the files I think are needed.  You will see some Toasts, this was me trying to figure out the logic of what I need to do

AiOhFarkActivity - Main Class

```
public class AiOhFarkActivity extends Activity implements AnimationEndListener {

    private AiGameController controller;
    private DieManager dm;

    private ArrayList<MyImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<MyImageView>();

    // Added for AI to set the starting
    // number of dice selected to 0
    private int selectedDie = -1;

    //public boolean performItemClick (View v, int position, long id);
    private int[] letters = new int[6];
    private boolean toFarkle = false;
    private int animationCount = 0;

    public Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Create, Initialize and then load the Sound manager and Volume Control
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        SoundManager.  ....

        r = getResources();
        initializeArrays();
        scoreBox = (TextView) ....
        numFarkles = (TextView) ....
        dieScore = (TextView) ....
        scoreButton = (Button) ....
        rollButton = (Button) ....
        finalButton = (Button) ....
        finalRoundLayout = (LinearLayout) ....
        winnerButton = (Button) ....
        winnerLayout = (LinearLayout) ....
        winnerTextView = (TextView) ....

        handler = new Handler();

        // Restore GameController
        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
                controller = (AiGameController) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                controller.newUI(this);
                updateImages(false, false);
        } else {
                controller = new AiGameController(this);
        }

        // Restore UI elements
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasState")) {

                scoreBox.setText ....
                numFarkles.setText ....
                dieScore.setText ....
                scoreButton.setText ....
                scoreButton.setEnabled ....
                rollButton.setEnabled ....
                finalButton.setEnabled ....
                finalRoundLayout.setEnabled ....
                winnerButton.setEnabled ....
                winnerButton.setText ....
                winnerLayout.setEnabled ....
        }
    }



    // These arrays allows the use of a for loop in updateImages()
    private void initializeArrays() {
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_1));
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_2));
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_3));
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_4));
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_5));
            imageViews.add((MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_6));

            letters[0] = R.drawable.dief;
            letters[1] = R.drawable.diea;
            letters[2] = R.drawable.dier;
            letters[3] = R.drawable.diek;
            letters[4] = R.drawable.diel;
            letters[5] = R.drawable.diee;
    }

    public void onRoll(View v) {
        controller.onRoll();

    }

    // TODO AI
    public void disableButtons(){

    }

    // TODO AI
    public void enableButtons(){
        rollButton.setClickable(true);
        scoreButton.setClickable(true);
    }

    // TODO AI
    public void disableDice(){

    }

    // TODO AI
    public void enableDice(){

    }

    public void onScore(View v) {
    // Calculate Score
    controller.onScore();

    //Play Sound
    if (myPrefs.getBoolean("soundPrefCheck", true)) {
        SoundManager. ....
    }

    // After Player Scores
    // Check to see if the Current Player is now the Machine
    // If machine player, roll the dice and lock
    // the buttons so the human cannot cheat
    // TODO AI
    if (controller.isMachinePlayer() == true) {
        controller.machineRoll();
        disableButtons();
        disableDice();
    }else {
        enableButtons();
        enableDice();
    }
}


    public void updateImages(boolean toAnimate, boolean isFarkle) {
            // This is used in onAnimationEnd() to determine when all animations
            // have ended. Since all the animations are starting when this method is
            // called the count is 0
            animationCount = 0;

            MyImageView i = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < imageViews.size(); j++) {

                    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.dice_animation);

                    i = imageViews.get(j);

                    // If were gonna animate we need to know when the animation ends.
                    // Hence were gonna attach this instance as a listener so
                    // onAnimationEnd() gets called when animations finish.
                    if (toAnimate) {
                            i.setAnimationEndListerner(this);
                    }

                    // Get the right image from the Resources. *See in DiceManager
                    // getImage()
                    i.setImageDrawable(r.getDrawable(controller.getImage(j)));
                    if (toAnimate && controller.shouldAnimate(j)) {
                            i.clearAnimation();
                            i.startAnimation(a);
                    }
            }

            // Used in onAnimatonEnds()
            if (isFarkle)
                    toFarkle = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
            return controller;
    }

    public void showFarkle() {

    }

    private void farkleAnimation() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(View v) {

    }


}
```

AiGameController

```
public class AiGameController extends PreferenceActivity {

        private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

        public AiGameController(AiOhFarkActivity ui) {
                setupPlayers(ui);

                dM = new DieManager();
                UI = ui;
                updateUIScore();

                currPlayer = players.get(round % players.size());
                lastPlayer = null;
                machinePlayer = players.get(round % players.size());

        }

        public void setupPlayers(Context c) {

                int numOfPlayers = 1;

                for (int i = 1; i <= numOfPlayers; i++) {

                        // TODO AI
                        String player = "Human  ";
                        String machine = "Machine";
                        players.add(new Player(player));
                        players.add(new Player(machine));
                }
        }

        // If the currPlayer is the Machine
        // TODO AI
        public void machineRoll() {
                // Check for Machine Player, if found Roll the dice
            // Check for Machine Player, if found Roll the dice
            if (currPlayer.getName() == "Machine"){
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    onRoll();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {

                                                    onClickDice(0, false);
                                                    onClickDice(1, false);
                                                    onClickDice(2, false);
                                                    onClickDice(3, false);
                                                    onClickDice(4, false);
                                                    onClickDice(5, false);

                                                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(350);

                                                    if (ppossibleScore >= GOB_SCORE){

                                                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                    public void run() {
                                                                            //Play Sound
                                                                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UI);
                                                                            if (prefs.getBoolean("soundPrefCheck", true)) {
                                                                                    SoundManager.playSound(11, 1);  // Flip Sound
                                                                            }
                                                                            onScore();
                                                                    }

                                                            }, 750);
                                                    }else {
                                                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                                    public void run() {
                                                                            // If the highest score possible on the table is 0 then its a farkle
                                                                            if (Scorer.calculate(dM.diceOnTable(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), true,
                                                                                    UI) == 0) {
                                                                                    currPlayer.setInRoundScore(0);
                                                                                    currPlayer.incrementNumOfFarkles();
                                                                                    // True because its a Farkle
                                                                                    endRound(true);
                                                                                    // Else just show what the player rolled
                                                                            } else
                                                                                    repaetMachineRoll();
                                                                    }
                                                            }, 750);
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }, 1750);

                                    // If all dice are selected (Hot Dice) onRoll again

                                    // Not sure if this belongs here ..... But,
                                    // If the numDiceRemaining <= 2 and the CurrScoreOnTable >= 300
                                    // bank the points - call onScore
                                    // if numDiceRemaining > 2 and CurrScoreOnTable <= 250 - call onRoll
                            }
                    }, 1750);
            }




        // If the currPlayer is the Machine
        public boolean isMachinePlayer() {
                // TODO Alert AI
                // Check for Machine Player, if found Roll the dice
                if (currPlayer.getName() == "Machine"){
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }


        // Always called from onRoll method
        public void startRound() {
                isRoundEnded = false;
                currPlayer = players.get(round % players.size());
                currPlayer.resetInRoundScore();
                machinePlayer = players.get(round % players.size());
                machinePlayer.resetInRoundScore();
                updateUIScore();

                // Show the Current Players Number of Farkles
                String fmessage = "";
                fmessage += UI.getString(R.string.stYouHave) + " " + currPlayer.getNumOfFarkles() + " " +  UI.getString(R.string.stFarkles);
                UI.updatenumOfFarkles(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(fmessage, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)));
        }

        // Can be called from onRoll or onScore
        public void endRound(boolean isFarkle) {

                if (!isFarkle)

                        UI.rollButtonState(true);
                UI.scoreButtonState(false);

                String pscore = UI.getString(R.string.stScore);
                UI.updatepPoints(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(pscore, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

                // show penalty
                SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UI);
                int farklePenaltyScore = Integer.valueOf(pref.getString("farklePenaltyPref", "-1000"));

                // Checks to see if Farkle Penalty is on
                if (pref.getBoolean("farklePenalty", true)) {
                        if (isFarkle && currPlayer.getNumOfFarkles() == 3) {
                                currPlayer.setInRoundScore(farklePenaltyScore);
                                // Show a -1000 next to his name
                                updateUIScore();
                                // There is a penalty *See animationsEnded()
                                negateFarklePenalty = true;
                        }
                }

                // Alert the UI a farkle is rolled
                UI.updateImages(false, isFarkle);

                // If its not a farkle then just clear the table and Update the images
                if (!isFarkle) {
                        dM.clearTable();
                        UI.updateImages(false, false);
                }

                isRoundEnded = true;

                round++;
                lastPlayer = currPlayer;
                currPlayer = players.get(round % players.size());

                // Usually updateUIScore() is called to erase the "+Score" but it
                // shouldn't be called if the last player farkled three times because it
                // erases the -1000
                if (lastPlayer.getNumOfFarkles() != 3)
                        updateUIScore();

                if (!isFarkle && currPlayer.hasHighestScore()) {
                        alertOfWinner();

                }
        }


        private void alertOfWinner() {

                showGameOver();
        }

        // Finds the player with the Highest score
        private int findHighestScore() {
                for (Player p : players) {
                        if (p.hasHighestScore())
                                return players.indexOf(p);
                }
                return -1;
        }

        // Updates the ScoreBox
        private void updateUIScore() {

                String message = "";

                for (Player p : players) {
                        if (p.equals(currPlayer)) {

                                int currInRoundScore = p.getInRoundScore();
                                String temp = "$$            ";
                                String sign = (currInRoundScore > 0) ? "+" : "";

                                if (currInRoundScore != 0 && !isRoundEnded)
                                        temp = "$$   " + sign + currInRoundScore + "    ";

                                message += "$$" + p.getName() + temp + p.getScore() + "\n";

                        } else {
                                message += p.getName() + "             " + p.getScore() + "\n";

                        }

                }

                // The $$ tell setSpanBetweenTokens() what to make bold
                UI.updateScoreBox(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(message, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

        }

        // Number of Current Die remaining on the table
        public int numOnTable() {
                return dM.numOnTable();
        }

        // Called when the roll button is clicked or can be called from the AI
        public void onRoll() {
                UI.finalRoundLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Sounds
                SharedPreferences mySoundPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UI);
                if (mySoundPref.getBoolean("soundPrefCheck", true)) {

                }

                // Reset Score Button
                String message = "";

                //message += "Dice Score: 0";


                // onRoll
                if (isRoundEnded)
                        startRound();

                UI.rollButtonState(false);
                UI.scoreButtonState(false);

                if (dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.INDEX_FLAG).length > 0) {

                        int scoreOnTable = Scorer.calculate(
                                dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), true, UI);

                        currPlayer.incrementInRoundScore(scoreOnTable);
                        // Show how much was picked up
                        updateUIScore();

                        dM.pickUp(dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.INDEX_FLAG));
                }

                dM.rollDice();

                UI.updateImages(true, false);

                // If the highest score possible on the table is 0 then its a farkle
                if (Scorer.calculate(dM.diceOnTable(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), true,
                        UI) == 0) {
                        currPlayer.setInRoundScore(0);
                        currPlayer.incrementNumOfFarkles();
                        // True because its a Farkle
                        endRound(true);
                        // Else just show what the player rolled
                } else
                        UI.updateImages(true, false);
                // Check for isMachinePlayer
        }

        // When a dice is clicked the GameController determines which dice to
        // highlight and whether to enable the buttons
        public void onClickDice(int index, boolean isFarkle) {

                // Play Select Sound
                SharedPreferences mySoundPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UI);
                if (mySoundPref.getBoolean("soundPrefCheck", true)) {
                        SoundManager.playSound(10, 1);  // Select Sound
                }

                String message = "";
                String pscore = "";

                if (isRoundEnded)
                        return;

                int value = dM.getValue(index, DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG);

                // A letter was clicked
                if (value == 0)
                        return;

                // Always highlight 5's and 1's
                if (value == 5 || value == 1) {

                        dM.toggleHighlight(index);

                } else {

                        // This method determines if the dice should be highlighted
                        if (shouldHighlight(index)) {

                                // if true then get the pairs of this dice
                                int[] pairs = dM.findPairs(index, DieManager.INDEX_FLAG);

                                // Highlight them
                                for (int i : pairs)
                                        dM.toggleHighlight(i);

                                // And highlight the original dice
                                dM.toggleHighlight(index);
                        }
                }

                // The score of the highlighted dice
                int highlightedScore = Scorer.calculate(dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), false, UI);
                // Second parameter is false to not ignore any extra dice

                // The score the player picked up
                int possibleScore = currPlayer.getInRoundScore() + highlightedScore + currPlayer.getScore();

                // Display the Current Score of the selected Dice
                //message += "Dice Score: " + highlightedScore;
                message += (UI.getString(R.string.stDiceScore)) + ": " + highlightedScore;
                UI.updateCurrentScore(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(message, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

                // Display the Potential Points in the Score Button
                int ppossibleScore = currPlayer.getInRoundScore() + highlightedScore;

                pscore = "+ " + ppossibleScore;
                UI.updatepPoints(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(pscore, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

                if (highlightedScore != 0) {
                        UI.rollButtonState(true);

                        // Play Hot Dice sound
                        if (mySoundPref.getBoolean("soundPrefCheck", true)) {
                                if (dM.numDiceRemain() == 0){
                                        SoundManager.playSound(8, 1);  // HotDice Sound
                                }
                        }

                        // Tells it when to enable the Score Button
                        // based on the Get-On-Board Value
                        if (possibleScore >= GOB_SCORE) {
                                UI.scoreButtonState(true);
                                showToast("GOB Score met");
                        }

                        // If a player is past the winning score
                        if (isPlayerPastWinScore) {

                                // Disable the score button
                                UI.scoreButtonState(false);

                                // The highest score so far
                                int scoreOfWinnerToBe = players.get(findHighestScore())
                                        .getScore();

                                // If the player can get a higher score then enable the score
                                // button
                                if (possibleScore > scoreOfWinnerToBe) {
                                        UI.scoreButtonState(true);
                                }
                        }
                } else {
                        UI.rollButtonState(false);
                        UI.scoreButtonState(false);
                }

                UI.updateImages(false, false);
        }

        // Calculate the current Score that is possible if banked.
        public int CurrScoreOnTable() {
                int highlightedScore = Scorer.calculate(dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), false, UI);
                int possibleScore = lastPlayer.getInRoundScore() + highlightedScore;
                return possibleScore;
        }

        // Determines whether to highlight the dice clicked
        private boolean shouldHighlight(int index) {

                // Gets the pairs (if any)
                int[] pairs = dM.findPairs(index, DieManager.INDEX_FLAG);

                int[] valuesOfPairs = new int[pairs.length + 1];

                // Takes the value of the pairs and puts them into the valueOfPairs
                // array
                System.arraycopy(dM.findPairs(index, DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG), 0, valuesOfPairs, 0, pairs.length);

                // Adds the dice that was clicked to the array
                valuesOfPairs[pairs.length] = dM.getValue(index, DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG);

                // True if the value of the pairs and the dice clicked is 0
                boolean isZero = Scorer.calculate(valuesOfPairs, false, UI) == 0;

                int[] diceOnTable = dM.diceOnTable(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG);

                // True is there are three pairs on the table
                boolean isThreePair = Scorer.isThreePair(diceOnTable, UI, true) != 0;

                // True if there is a straight on the table
                boolean isStraight = Scorer.isStraight(diceOnTable, UI, true) != 0;

                return (!isZero || isThreePair || isStraight);
        }

        // Score button is clicked.
        public void onScore() {
                // Reset the Current Dice Score and Make Roll Button Active
                String message = "";
                // message += "Dice Score: 0";

                message += (UI.getString(R.string.stDiceScore)) + ": 0";

                UI.updateCurrentScore(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(message, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

                String pscore = UI.getString(R.string.stScore);
                UI.updatepPoints(UTILS.setSpanBetweenTokens(pscore, "$$", new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)));

                // Values of highlighted dice on table
                int[] highlighted = dM.getHighlighted(DieManager.ABS_VALUE_FLAG);
                // Score of the highlighted dice
                int onTable = Scorer.calculate(highlighted, false, UI);
                // The players new Score
                int newScore = currPlayer.getScore() + onTable + currPlayer.getInRoundScore();
                currPlayer.setScore(newScore);

                if (newScore >= WINNING_SCORE) {
                        //SharedPreferences myPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                        isPlayerPastWinScore = true;
                        // If no one is over the WINNING_SCORE findWinnerToBe() returns -1
                        if (findHighestScore() == -1) {
                                // Player is the first one to pass the score
                                currPlayer.setOriginalWinner(true);
                                currPlayer.setHasHighestScore(true);

                        } else {
                                currPlayer.setHasHighestScore(true);
                        }
                }

                currPlayer.resetInRoundScore();

                // False because its not a Farkle

                endRound(false);

                // Show the Current PLayers Number of Farkles

        }

        public int getImage(int index) {
                return dM.getImage(index);
        }

        public void newUI(AiOhFarkActivity newUI) {
                UI = newUI;
        }

        // Should not animate if value of dice is 0 ie its a letter
        public boolean shouldAnimate(int index) {
                return (dM.getValue(index, DieManager.VALUE_FLAG) > 0);
        }

        public void clearTable() {
                dM.clearTable();
        }


        public void animationsEnded(boolean isFarkle) {

        }

}
```

DieManager

```
public class DieManager {

    // Will return the Indexes of the dice when this is used
    public static final int INDEX_FLAG = 1;
    // Will return the values of the dice when this is used
    public static final int VALUE_FLAG = 2;
    // Will return the absolute values of the dice when this is used
    public static final int ABS_VALUE_FLAG = 3;

    // The array that holds the dice
    private int[] diceValues = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> diceImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> deadImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> letterImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    // Sets @newValue to dieValues[@index]
    public void setValue(int index, int newValue) {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Index = " + index + " Value = " + newValue);
        diceValues[index] = newValue;
    }

    public DieManager() {
        super();
        initializeMaps();


    }

    private void initializeMaps() {

        // Shows Selected 
        diceImages.put(-6, R.drawable.die6_select);
        diceImages.put(-5, R.drawable.die5_select);
        diceImages.put(-4, R.drawable.die4_select);
        diceImages.put(-3, R.drawable.die3_select);
        diceImages.put(-2, R.drawable.die2_select);
        diceImages.put(-1, R.drawable.die1_select);

        // Shows Rolled
        diceImages.put(1, R.drawable.die1_roll);
        diceImages.put(2, R.drawable.die2_roll);
        diceImages.put(3, R.drawable.die3_roll);
        diceImages.put(4, R.drawable.die4_roll);
        diceImages.put(5, R.drawable.die5_roll);
        diceImages.put(6, R.drawable.die6_roll);

        // dice are dead 
        deadImages.put(0, R.drawable.die1_dead);
        deadImages.put(1, R.drawable.die2_dead);
        deadImages.put(2, R.drawable.die3_dead);
        deadImages.put(3, R.drawable.die4_dead);
        deadImages.put(4, R.drawable.die5_dead);
        deadImages.put(5, R.drawable.die6_dead);

        // Shows blank
        letterImages.put(0, R.drawable.die_no);
        letterImages.put(1, R.drawable.die_no);
        letterImages.put(2, R.drawable.die_no);
        letterImages.put(3, R.drawable.die_no);
        letterImages.put(4, R.drawable.die_no);
        letterImages.put(5, R.drawable.die_no);

    }

    public void rollDice() {

        showToast("Rolling Dice");

        boolean isNewRound = (numOnTable() == 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (isNewRound || diceValues[j] != 0)
                diceValues[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        }
    }

    // Returns the value or absolute value
    public int getValue(int index, int flag) {
        if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
            return Math.abs(diceValues[index]);
        return diceValues[index];
    }

    // If a dice value is 0 then its a letter
    public int numOnTable() {
        int count = 6;
        for (int i : diceValues) {
            if (i == 0)
                count--;
        }
        return count;
    }

    // Picking up makes the dice value 0
    public void pickUp(int[] highlighted) {

        for (int i = 0; i < highlighted.length; i++)
            diceValues[highlighted[i]] = 0;

    }

    // A negative value means a die is highlighted
    public void toggleHighlight(int index) {
        diceValues[index] *= -1;
    }

    public void clearTable() {
        diceValues[0] = 0;
        diceValues[1] = 0;
        diceValues[2] = 0;
        diceValues[3] = 0;
        diceValues[4] = 0;
        diceValues[5] = 0;

    }

    // Return the dice that aren't 0
    public int[] diceOnTable(int flag) {
        showToast("Getting Dice Values");
        if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG) {
            int[] array = new int[diceValues.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < diceValues.length; i++)
                array[i] = Math.abs(diceValues[i]);

            return array;
        }

        return diceValues;
    }

    //Returns dice that are negative
    public int[] getHighlighted(int flag) {
        int[] dirtyArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (diceValues[j] < 0) {

                if (flag == INDEX_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = j;

                if (flag == VALUE_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = diceValues[j];

                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = Math.abs(diceValues[j]);
            }
        }

        int[] cleanArray = new int[count];

        //Returns an array of length 0
        if (count == 0)
            return cleanArray;

        System.arraycopy(dirtyArray, 0, cleanArray, 0, count);
        return cleanArray;

    }

    // Finds in dieValues same @value and excludes @index
    public int[] findPairs(int index, int flag) {

        int[] dirtyArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

            if (j != index
                    && Math.abs(diceValues[j]) == Math.abs(diceValues[index])) {

                if (flag == INDEX_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = j;

                if (flag == VALUE_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = diceValues[j];

                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
                    dirtyArray[count++] = Math.abs(diceValues[j]);
            }

        }

        int[] cleanArray = new int[count];

        if (count == 0)
            return cleanArray;

        System.arraycopy(dirtyArray, 0, cleanArray, 0, count);
        return cleanArray;
    }

    //Get the Dice Images
    public Integer getImage(int index) {
        if (diceValues[index] == 0) {
            return letterImages.get(index);
        } else {
            return diceImages.get((diceValues[index]));
        }
    }

    //Get the Number of dice remaining that are not 0
    public int numDiceRemain() {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < diceValues.length; j++) {
            if (diceValues[j] > 0)
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }


    public void selectDice() {
        // TODO Alert AI

    }

    public void selectAllDice() {
        // TODO Alert AI
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated the code above to show selecting ALL dice. Still need to figure out how to do this better and 1 by 1 as well as the rest of the logic.

Comment: Too much code. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Instead of trying to find which image it is, it's a much better design to store the actual value corresponding to each picture and read that.